# Post from request body with HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest

Trying to consume a REST api using HttpClient. Im required to pass username and password through the body. Below is my code,Its however not posting the data values;

```
 var data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        { {"username","username"},
         {"password","password"}};
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        HttpClient client2 = new HttpClient();
        var requestContent2 = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
        HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client2.PostAsync(nitaauthapi, requestContent2);
        HttpContent content2 = response2.Content;
        string result2 = await content2.ReadAsStringAsync();
        JObject jObject2 = JObject.Parse(result2);
        string NONCE = jObject2["NONCE"].Value<string>();
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @Heinzi the texts on username section were accidental, i have formatted the code correctly now. The question here is what im doing wring, the api doesn't seem to get the data its expecting on body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you correctly encode your data as JSON:

```
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

Afterwards, you *ignore* your JSON-encoded data and instead send the string `` "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]" `` (= the output of `data.ToString()`) to your API endpoint:

```
var requestContent2 = new StringContent(data.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

To fix this, use `jsonData` in your StringContent instead of `data.ToString()`.

---

How to avoid such issues in the future: **Pay attention to Visual Studio's hints.** Visual Studio will highlight `jsonData` in a light grey color and add three dots underneath to inform you that something might be wrong with it:

[image: code example]

Hovering over it will produce a tooltip telling you that the variable's value is unused.